# How do I sort data in google sheets by word length?

Tags: google-sheets

I was wondering how to sort data in google sheets by how many letters it contains. Could someone help me with this? Please explain clearly as I am new to google sheets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=INDEX(SORT(A2:A; LEN(A2:A); 1))
```

or 0 instead of 1 for reverse ordering

Answer (score 0):

#### Sort by Length

In sheets it is relatively easy to sort by string length using the SORT and LEN functions.

```
=SORT(A2:A, LEN(A2:A), TRUE )
```

#### Issues

Using the formula above can be problematic if:

1. there are a lot of 'duplicates' based on string length which will not be sorted relative to each other;
2. there are empty cells in your range. Especially problematic when sorting in ascending order since all blank cells `LEN("")` will be sorted before any populated cells;

#### Solution

The 'duplicates' can be sorted relative to each other using the SORT function's optional secondary SORT.

The QUERY function will allow the formula to return only non-blank values.

#### Better Formula

This formula will SORT by LEN ascending then will SORT any duplicate lengths  alphanumericaly. Finally any blank values will be removed.

```
=QUERY(
   SORT(A2:A,
        LEN(A2:A), TRUE,
        1, TRUE),
   "Select * where Col1 <>'' ")
```

#### Approaches Compared

| Cell | Formula |
| --- | --- |
| B2 ***** | `=SORT(A2:A15, LEN(A2:A15), TRUE)` ***** |
| C2 | `=QUERY(SORT(A2:A,LEN(A2:A, TRUE), "Select * where Col1 <>'' ")` |
| D2 | `=QUERY(SORT(A2:A, LEN(A2:A, TRUE, 1, TRUE), "Select * where Col1 <>'' ")` |

<sup>***** `A2:A15` *used in* `B2` *to better illustrate empty cell issue*</sup>

**<sub>Approaches Compared</sub>**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers have shown how to sort information in one column into another column by length. If you want to sort an entire sheet by the length of a particular column, you can do the following:

Assuming you want to sort by the A column:

1. Choose an empty column, say it's B.
2. In B1, enter =len(A1)
3. Drag-fill column B with the formula.
4. Click on B to select the whole column.
5. Copy
6. Right-click on B, hover Paste special, and select Values only
7. Sort the sheet by column B
8. Delete column B